# Can Findbugs detect catching RuntimeException in java?

Tags: findbugs

Could you let me know taht Findbugs can detect catcing RuntimeException in java?

Effective java recommends that we should not catch RuntimeException.

So I want to know that Findbugs can grab wrong catching.

Additionally, I already checked Klocwork JD.CATCH and checkstyle IllegalCatch is appropriate for this purpose.

Comment: The best tool for catching 'RuntimeException ' is the one on top on your neck...

Comment: But why not automate it, if you can... sometimes you inherit a large codebase full of trivial errors, that static analysis can catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of.
In findbugs there are several bug detectors dealing with exceptions:

- [DE:](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#DE_MIGHT_DROP) Method might drop exception
- [DE:](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#DE_MIGHT_IGNORE) Method might ignore exception
- [Nm:](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#NM_CLASS_NOT_EXCEPTION) Class is not derived from an Exception, even though it is named as such
- [RV:](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#RV_EXCEPTION_NOT_THROWN) Exception created and dropped rather than thrown
- [REC:](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#REC_CATCH_EXCEPTION) Exception is caught when Exception is not thrown

and also [findbugs-contrib](http://fb-contrib.sourceforge.net/bugdescriptions.html) (findbugs plugin) has some:

- BED_BOGUS_EXCEPTION_DECLARATION
- DRE_DECLARED_RUNTIME_EXCEPTION
- EXS_EXCEPTION_SOFTENING_NO_CHECKED
- EXS_EXCEPTION_SOFTENING_HAS_CHECKED
- EXS_EXCEPTION_SOFTENING_NO_CONSTRAINTS

Try those out and check if they match your requirements (especially the last one (REC) of fb). However if you plainly need to detect the following pattern:

```
catch ( RuntimeException re){
    ....            
}
```

You may need to implement your own (quite easy) bug pattern for findbugs...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm reviewing Findbugs bug patterns. Could you let me know what keywords such as 'DE' or 'Nm' mean?

Comment: Those are just abbreviations - like REC probably means 'Runtime Exception Catch(ing)' or EXS means EXception Softening'. But for you, the enduser there is no special meaning to it...